# Coq proving addition inequality

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am a beginner and trying to prove this lemma:

```
Lemma test:  forall n m p q : nat,
    n <= p \/ m <= q -> n + m <= p + q.
```

I tried

```
From Coq Require Export Lia.

Lemma test:  forall n m p q : nat,
        n <= p \/ m <= q -> n + m <= p + q
Proof.
    intros; omega.
```

and `Lia`, but it is not working. How could I proceed?

Comment: You should be importing Lia, not exporting it. That's what's causing your tactic failure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant

```
Lemma test:  forall n m p q : nat,
    n <= p /\ m <= q -> n + m <= p + q.
```

with `/\` (logical and) rather than `\/` (logical or) because your theorem does not hold otherwise. As a counterexample, pick n = p = q = 0 and m = 1.

When fixed that way, lia finds the proof automatically.

Also, note it is more idiomatic in Coq to currify types, that is replacing conjunction on the left of an arrow with an arrow. This would read

```
Lemma test:  forall n m p q : nat,
    n <= p -> m <= q -> n + m <= p + q.
```

which is equivalent.

Comment: @ieja please mark the answer as accepted, by clicking on the upper triangle on the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. However,

```
Proof.
  intros. lia.
```

gives:

```
Error: Tactic failure:  Cannot find witness.
```

Is there a way to proceed?

Comment: I would add this as an edit to your question, and not as an answer.

Comment: Or perhaps if you can put it more succinctly, as a comment on @perthmad's answer below. (Though I think my comment on your question answers this)